# {M1) Product collection sort order by views for Most Viewed Products

Tags: magento-1.9, order-collection

Does anyone know how to order by views (ascending/descending) a product collection when working with most viewed products?

I am using this following code:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productIds)
    ;
```

I am getting the most viewed product in a time range but always the collection is ordered descending mainly because method addViewsCount() orders collection views descending.

In file /app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Product/Collection.php (line 375)

```
    ->order('views ' . self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
```

I would like to order my collection by views, ascending and descending, but views is not an attribute to use in setOrder() method.